# Button with name = submit becoming disable while using boot strap validations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqbootstrapvalidation

I am facing a very strange issue.

I have a simple form with a text box. I have two buttons of type submit. If I set `name = submit` on one of those buttons then buttons are becoming disabled when clicked and not getting posted.

Is this the standard behavior in a boot strap or this can be changed?

Comment: post your code as well

Comment: Post your code. Wrap submit in quotes.

Comment: Post the relevant code please!

Answer (score 1):

You should not name any form element "submit" since that will mask/eclipse the JavaScript [form.submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) function and it will not be available!

You can address any form field by its name using `document["nameOfForm"]["nameOfField"]` or `document.nameOfForm.nameOfField`.  There are already form properties like `document.myForm.name` or methods like `document.myForm.submit()`.

Using names of form properties or methods that are already defined by the browser will interfere with any functionality that depends on them.

Other common field names to avoid:

- action
- enctype
- method
- name
- target

It appears your JS library of choice is using `form.submit()` to submit the form.

Comment: But that problem is coming if I am using the boot strap validations if I remove the bootstrap validation then its works fine with button name submit

Comment: @user3592182: Indeed, validation routines do not need to call form.submit() they can just handle the onsubmit event and return true or false from that.  If you're using somebody elses framework you're restricted to doing things the way the framework is designed I'm afraid.  If you used no JavaScript, all HTML form element names work.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the properties of a form, such as submit, reset, length, method to set the name or id attribute of form, field elements. Name conflicts can cause the problem.

For example, you cannot submit the form after validating if use submit to name the Submit button:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

[DOMLint](http://kangax.github.io/domlint/) has a complete list of rules to check the markup for these kind of problems.

Reference : [the name conflict warning](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/getting-started/#name-conflict) in the official documentation.